# Firefox issue calculating width w/ CSS inline-block & absolute positioning? (Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu)

Tags: firefox, css-float, css

I am using the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) HTML/CSS framework, and specifically the [dropdown menus](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation).  I'm attempting to add a "keyboard shortcut" that would be visible and right-aligned within each menu item.  The menu's width should adjust to fit its contents -- both the item name (left aligned) and the keyboard shortcut (right aligned) with some padding in between.

I have this working, with the exception of Firefox rendering the menu without including the width of the keyboard shortcut when it calculates the width of the menu!  (Works fine in webkit / specifically Chrome.)  Here's a screenshot illustrating how in Firefox the keyboard shortcut elements slide behind the primary menu text:

[image: screenshot]

I've boiled this down to a relatively simple page demonstrating the issue -- see [this jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/YTPqR/1/).

I can make Firefox render correctly if I make sure that no DIVs that are parents of the menu are "position: absolute;".  See the two lines I've marked to comment out in the CSS.  However, I don't see why I can't use absolute positioning for the containing blocks and why that would cause any difference between browsers.

Any clues of how I can resolve this without removing the absolute positioning of containing blocks?  Thanks.

Comment: It *only* works in WebKit browsers - it doesn't work in any of Firefox, IE8/9, Opera.

Comment: tried adding a width value to the shortcut a?

Answer (score 1):

First, it does no good to put both `position: absolute` and `float` on the same element, as they are mutually exclusive forms of positioning (`absolute` overrides `float`). You can eliminate one or the other depending on your needs. Determine which is more important for what you need to do.

Second, it appears that having two `absolute` divs nested you need to give some width to help it know something is inside. When I put `width:100%` on the `.topbar` and `.nav` it allowed the menu to take shape. But I don't know if width is viable for your situation.

You can absolutely position the `.topbar` without `width` and eliminate the `absolute` on both child elements and it seemed to work also.

I can't give much more of a solution, because I don't know specifically how you want it to function and position.